# Run exe application and run his internal commands using one action

Tags: exe, autorun

I have an exe-application which I close and run many times in day. 
Every time when I'm running this application after as it started I must do some actions: choose "File" menu and choose file in there.

Is there is a way, how I can do this process more automatically: like a tapping on my exe app and after that all other actions are auto running?

I thought to use VMWare ThinApp for that. Just running my application with choosing parameters and then making image of it, but this way is not good for my work.

May be there is another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout AutoIt.

It is good for quickly automating simple tasks like clicking.

For example, if you can use shortcut keys, an example script could be:

```
Send("^o")                       ;Send CTRL+O
Mouseclick("left",$x,$y,1,3)     ;Click on the file name input box
Send("FileName.file{ENTER}")     ;Type in the name of the file and hit enter
Mouseclick("left",$x,$y,1,3)     ;Check a box ...
```

https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/